# Displaying categories in different template problem

Tags: categories, templates

Greetings!

Sorry for the vague title decription - Couldn't word it any different.

In my index.php page I have the following code:

```
<?php  if (is_category('6')) { ?>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/blog.php'); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) {
      $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
      query_posts("cat=5&paged=$paged");} ?>
```

Now, I'd like to include another category in the 'blog.php' template, but simply adding the cat number in the first line, like:

```
<?php  if (is_category('6, 7')) { ?>
```

is not working and simply ignores both.

Any idea of what I'm missing here, or perhaps a better way to do it altogether?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it in an array.

```
<?php if(is_category(array(1,2,3,4)) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, This works! It was just missing the left gullwing, as in: